I’m using curl to read from discord, but it’s just showing a white screen
So I made the website and the code but it can’t seem to work
<?php

if (isset($_GET['src'])) {
    $url = $_GET['src'];
    
    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) && strpos($url, 'cdn.discordapp.com') !== false) {
        
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($result !== false) {
            echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($result) . "</pre>";
        } else {
            echo "Error fetching the content.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid URL     provided.";
    }
} else {
    echo "No URL specified.";
}
?>

I tried to ask my friends but they didn’t know how to solve the issue neither

I don't see any obvious syntax errors, and you seem to have enough echos for all possibilities. I'd suggest checking your server's error logs to see if there's any information there. You can also check the source in the browser to see if it's just sending empty <pre></pre> tags, which means it's working, but $result is empty.

Check the PHP error logs, enable PHP error reporting to the page, check the returned page source to ensure it's not just responding with the PHP code itself, add useful debugging output to the page, etc.  Essentially you're at the point where you need to debug and narrow down the problem, which at this time could be just about anything.

You see, any question involving a "blank screen" boils down to "how to get th error message/debug output" no matter what exactly you're trying to do

Okay thank you, btw if you need more info, try yourself with my website | https://kosmo6666.one/txt/?src=(discord atrachment link)

Please provide an example URL that you pass to your script.

If all we're going to get by testing your site ourselves is a blank screen then that won't help us, or you - it gives us no information about the underlying problem. You need to debug properly and check thoroughly for errors, as we've already mentioned
